# Free/libre comic strip creator for GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, images, image-editor

I want to create [comic strips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_strip). But, as I have no artistic talent, I can’t picture them by hand. So I’m looking for a tool that allows me to arrange "templates", like

- characters,
- furniture,
- items, and
- speech balloons.

(The more templates the better. It would be great if new templates can be imported and if there’s also a community that creates them.)

#### The tool …

- MUST support adding text to speech balloons.
- MUST allow to **export** a comic strip in a well-known format that can be opened by "everyone" (for example: HTML, PNG, JPG, PDF, …).
- SHOULD NOT automatically add watermarks/attribution to the exported comics.

#### Formal requirements

- It MUST be **FLOSS** (Free/Libre Open Source Software).

  - Supplied graphics/templates MUST be licensed under the same license OR under a free content license.
- It MUST run natively on **GNU/Linux**.
- It MUST be a **desktop** client OR a **Web** application (still FLOSS).

Comment: I haven't use it but take a look at tbo https://github.com/danigm/tbo

Comment: It might take some time to learn but you could try Scratch. It runs on Linux, Windows, and Mac (http://scratch.mit.edu/scratch_1.4/). It also has a web app (http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/?tip_bar=getStarted)

Comment: Krita and Scratch seem overkill; I don't know TBO. http://stripgenerator.com/ is the kind of thing you need, but it definitely looks proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [Krita](https://krita.org/)

Krita is a FREE and OPEN-SOURCE digital painting and illustration application.

Krita offers CMYK support, HDR painting, perspective grids, dockers, filters, painting assistants, and many other features you would expect.

Here are some examples of what one could do with it:

[image: !Girl1]

[image: !Girl2]

From [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krita):

> Krita is a raster graphics editor based on the KDE Platform. It is also a part of Calligra Suite. Krita is designed to be a digital painting application. It has been influenced to some extent by software like Corel Painter and SAI. Krita packs with some key features different than most of its kind, including the ability to work with both bitmap and vector illustration. The developers also try to simplify user interaction and focus features more relevant to painting and drawing.
>
> Krita is a free software distributed under GNU General Public License version 2 and above. It was initially released as a part of KOffice version 1.4.0, on June 21, 2005.

Comment: Wouldn’t this tool require me to "picture them by hand"? Or does it come with comic templates?

Comment: Krita is the opposite of the answer to this question. OP says he can't draw. Krita is for drawing...