# Adding speech bubbles to photographs

Tags: linux, open-source, images, image-editor

I want to add [speech balloons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_balloon) to photographs.

Bonus points for supporting other bubbles, too (thought bubbles, scream bubbles, …).

I want to

1. open the photograph,
2. add a speech bubble,
3. enter text, and
4. drag and drop it to its intended position.

Wish list:

- The entered text should never overflow.
- The text and the bubble should "stick" together so that I can freely move them as a unit.
- It would be great if I could resize and/or move the pointer/tail so that the actual bubble/text can be farther away.
- There must be no watermarks (or similar) on the result.

I’d love to find a small, specialized tool; but a bulky image editor is fine, too, as long as I don’t have to create/draw the bubbles by hand.

I’m using JPG, but I’m willing to convert if need be.

The tool must run natively on **GNU/Linux** and be **FLOSS**.

Comment: Visitors interested in this question might also be interested in: [Free/libre comic strip creator for GNU/Linux](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1060/60)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[LibreOffice Draw](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/)** can do that:

- runs natively on Linux
- the text and bubble stick together (as long as you double-clicked the bubble and inserted the text)
- drag the pointer/tail
- no watermarks
- not good: it includes the image in a page sized frame even if you choose to open the image directly with Draw. However if you press <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and export selection as image everything is ok.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also, https://www.pizap.com/app online service worked for me.