# Free software for painting cartoons

Tags: open-source, windows-7, images, image-editor, color

I would like to paint pictures of characters on PC (Windows 7).

I need a software which lets me change the color of (for example) hair with just one click.
In other words, I would like to change all color in cartoon picture to white.

Comment: Possibly related unanswered question: [‘Free/libre comic strip creator for GNU/Linux’](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/free-libre-comic-strip-creator-for-gnu-linux).

Comment: This isn't what I want...

Comment: Then you have to particularize your needs in order to get a meaningful answer, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this free utility http://www.gimp.org/ to change all color in cartoon picture to white.

**GIMP** is the **GNU Image Manipulation Program**. It is freely piece if distributed piece of software for  such tasks as *photo retouching, image composition and image authoring*. It works on many **Operating System**, in many **languages**.